# Flutter : How to set container size as wrap_content in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to set `Container` size dynamic I mean `wrap_content` how to do in flutter?

In below code `Container` take full width by default but I want to set width in `Container` as `Text()` long as

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.orange[800],
          child: Text("Hello How are you"),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.yellow[800],
          child: Text("Welcome"),
        )
      ],
    );
```

I get this :

[image]

But I Want this output :

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

The easiest solution is to use `Align`.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Colors.orange[800],
        child: Text("Hello How are you"),
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Colors.yellow[800],
        child: Text("Welcome"),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your **Container** with **Row**

```
    Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.orange[800],
                    child: Text("Hello How are you"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.yellow[800],
                    child: Text("Welcome"),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution can be, remove `alignment: Alignment.center,` from both `Container` and wrap `Column` inside a `Center` like this,

```
 Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.orange[800],
              child: Text("Hello How are you"),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.yellow[800],
              child: Text("Welcome"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap your Container with Row or Column**

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
            Container(
                color: CoreUiUtils.getColorFromHex("#292B2B"),
                width: deviceWidth,
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        Text("Title "),
                        Text("Description"),
                    ],
                )),
        ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to wrap your container content is not setting any height to that widget.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Wrap your Container with Row or Column
then set it size min

Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Text(
                "Hello"
            )
          ),
      ],
```

)